# Erro em font python 2x

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Estou tentando criar fontes separadas para meu projeto em um determinado arquivo.py, depois de criá-las eu importo para o projeto.py, faço isso da seguinte maneira:

fonte.py

```py
"""
Criando as fontes.
"""
def fontes(self):
    self.font1=("Arial", "60")
```

projeto.py

```py
 from Tkinter import *
 from fonte import *

 class base:
    def __init__(self, janela):
        caixa=Frame(janela)
        caixa.pack()
        a=Label(caixa, text="teste para o funcionamento das fontes", font=self.font1)
        a.pack()
        root=Tk()
        base(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Porem quando tento usar a fonte:

```py
a = Label(caixa, text="teste para o funcionamento das fontes", font=font1)
```

Está dando erro e diz que ela não é global:

> NameError: global name 'font1' is not defined

Alguém poderia me dizer como posso fazer o uso de fontes sem ser dentro do próprio projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque o sistema está buscando a variável 'font1' que no seu caso nunca foi declarada.

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

fonte.py

```
import tkfont

def fontes(self):
    arial = Font(family="Arial",size=60,weight="normal") 
    return arial
```

projeto.py

```
...
a=Label(caixa, text="teste para o funcionamento das fontes", font=fontes())
...
```

Comment: Oi -  então o código que você colocou aqui devem estar ok (não testei, mas não parece bom -- pensando bem, pq. sua função "fontes" tem o parâmetro "self"?? Não parece mais tão bom... :-/) - mas o O.P. está com dúvidas sobre como Python funciona, confundindo funções com classes, por exemplo, usando más práticas reconhecidas (`from X import * `)  - o que acha de dar um toque sobre essas coisas pra melhorar a sua resposta. I.e.: esclarecendo o que está errado, não só postando algumas linhas que funcionam?